# Discrepancy in the measurement of distance(measure line) in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am and my fellow colleague both of us using same version QGIS i.e., QGIS 2.8.3 and same CRS - NAD27 EPSG:4267, the problem is when we measure certain length of the feature(Using measure line option in QGIS), in her QGIS it displays say for ex: 300m and in mine the same length will be displayed as 450m. I crosschecked the results with some manual measurement the one displayed as 300m is correct. Also, we figured that this discrepancy is only for x- co-ordinate( Horizontally). Why such discrepancy even though we are using same version and same CRS. What settings can help us to get same and correct resutls?

Comment: Are you measuring the same feature from the same file?

Comment: Yes, same feature of same file

Comment: Also, we figured out that when i switch off and on the "On the Fly''(OTF), the one which was displaying as 450m before(i.e., before switching off and on the "On the Fly''(OTF) will display as 300m now, why so?

Comment: 2.8.3 is very old - I'd strongly recommend upgrading

Comment: Old versions of QGIS had many measurement discrepancies. Upgrade to the new version and most of those issues will be solved.

Comment: What have you set in your OTF settings? It does not have anything to do with measurement discrepancy but is most likely due to correct behavior of the program. QGIS does use the CRS set in the OTF for measuring, even if the file itself might be something else. That is what OTF is meant for. It often happens when you load basemaps using the web mercator EPSG: 3857 as this one may have those large distortions (it is meant for display, not measuring). It does (most likely) not have anything to do with the program and will be this way in other GIS as well!

Comment: In OTF settings i will set the CRS of the layer, then i will measure the length@Matte.
Then any suggestion, to measure any side(length) of the polygon? probably the best way, so that i will get correct and accurate result